# Python median filter applied to 3D array to produce 2D result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering, median

I had seen several discussions in this forum about applying median filter with moving window, but my application have a special peculiarity.

I have a 3D array of dimension **750x12000x10000** and I need to apply a median filter to result in a 2D array (12000x10000). For this, each median calculation should consider a fixed neighborhood window (usually **100x100**) and **all z-axis** values. There are some zero values in the matrix and they should not be considered for the calculation of the median. To proccessing real data, I am using `numpy.memmap`:

```
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(750, 12000, 10000))
```

To proccessing the real data stored with memmap, my input array is subdivided into several chunks, but to increase the speed of my tests, I will use in this post a reduced array **(11, 200, 300)** and a smaller window **(11, 5, 5)** or (11, 50, 50)  and I expect a result matrix (200, 300):

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

zsize, ysize, xsize = (11, 200, 300)
w_size = 5 #to generate a 3D window (all_z, w_size, w_size)
#w_size = 50 #to generate a 3D window (all_z, w_size, w_size)

m_in=np.arange(zsize*ysize*xsize).reshape(zsize, ysize, xsize)
m_out = np.zeros((ysize, xsize))
```

First, I've tried the brute force method, but it is very slow as expected (even for the small array):

```
start = timer()
for l in range(0, ysize):
    i_l = max(0, l - w_size/2)
    o_l = min(ysize, i_l+w_size/2)
    for c in range(0, xsize):
        i_c = max(0, c - w_size/2)
        o_c = min(xsize, i_c+w_size/2)
        values = m_in[:, i_l:o_l, i_c:o_c]
        values = values[np.nonzero(values)]
        value = np.median(values)
        m_out[l, c] = value
end = timer()
print("Time elapsed: %f seconds"%(end-start))
#11.7 seconds with 50 in z, 7.9 seconds with 5 in z
```

To remove the double-for, I tried to use `itertools.product`, but it still remains slow:

```
from itertools import product
for l, c in product(range(0, ysize), range(0, xsize)):
    i_l = max(0, l - w_size/2)
    o_l = min(ysize, i_l+w_size/2)
    i_c = max(0, c - w_size/2)
    o_c = min(xsize, i_c+w_size/2)
    values = m_in[:, i_l:o_l, i_c:o_c]
    values = values[np.nonzero(values)]
    value = np.median(values)
    m_out[l, c] = value
#11.7 seconds with 50 in z, 2.3 seconds with 5
```

So I tried to use the performance of matrix operations of numpy, so I tried with `scipy.ndimage`:

```
from scipy import ndimage
m_all = ndimage.median_filter(m_in, size=(zsize, w_size, w_size))
m_out[:] = m_all[0] #only first layer of 11, considering all the same
#a lot of seconds with 50 in z, 7.9 seconds with 5
```

and `scipy.signal` too:

```
m_all = signal.medfilt(m_in, kernel_size=(zsize, w_size, w_size))
m_out[:] = m_all[0] #only first layer of 11, considering all the same
#a lot of seconds with 50 in z, 7.8 seconds with 5 in z
```

But in both scipy cases, there are a waste of processing because the function is applied in all 3D positions of input matrix, however, it could be applied only in the first layer using a sliding window with dimension (all_z, w_size, w_size).

In all my tests, I did not had an fast execution time even when I used the reduced matrix and windows ((11, 200, 300) and (11, 50, 50)). The performance will be even more critical using my real data (an array of 750x12000x10000, and window of 750x100x100).

Please, can anyone help me to apply the median filter (3D array to 2D array) with a more best *pythonic* way?

**Edit1**
The real data array has many zero values. When considering a single axis, of the 750 values, about 15 are non-zero values. The zeros must be discarded in the processing, and because of this, I am not using a sparse array representation.

Comment: What is the real shape/ array order of your data? In the text it is (10000x12000x750), but in the memmap example it is in a different order (750, 12000, 10000)? Why are you using a non-chunked array here, with several drawbacks (only the fastest changing dimension can be accessed efficiently)?

Comment: Sorry, my error in writing the explanation. My actual data array has dimensions (750, 12000, 10000). I submitted the allocation code with a different dimension because I was testing if there was any gain using a different stride, but I'll edit it to avoid confusion. Yes, I'm using chunked access, but only to read the chunks coming from the memmap. I copy the entire array to the memmap at once, because in my tests, chunked access to the original data structure (gdal.Dataset) was a bit slower than memmap, but I can change this if you suggest a better way to do.

Comment: If your sparsity in the data array is 98%, then you should really think about this problem differently. Effectively, you have multiple measurements for most locations in x,y (but presumably for some locations you have no data), and you are trying to estimate a local average. Definitely convert to a sparse format to do that.

Comment: If your support is roughly uniform (the number of data points does not vary much by region), then pretty much any grid based interpolation is fine. If it does vary, I would suggest a k-nearest neighbor average (I have a weighted k-nearest neighbor mean implementation [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/inverse_distance_weighting), but getting a median of your k-nearest data points in x,y would be trivial, too)).

Comment: Thank you by your comment and suggestion Paul. Yes, my data is about 98% sparse, but only in one single axis. Maybe is more easy to think the data with dimension (12000, 10000, 750), because in this way, all (x,y) have values, but in the z-axis it does not have all 750 values, but only 20 nonzero (2%).

Comment: The interpolation is not suitable for this case because I dont want to fill my matrix, I want to sinthetyze a 3D array to result a 2D array. The array dimension of my data is comutable, because its depends of the way I read the input values. To improve the storage/proccessing using a more best structure, I can change the way of read and the array dimensions without any worse the proccessing. Sorry if I misunderstood your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being too long for a comment:

If you were applying a mean-filter, this problem would be trivial: you would take the mean over the z-axis and then apply the mean filter in 2D; this would be exactly equivalent to computing the mean over the full (x,y,z) neighbourhood in one go as the mean operation is associative (if that is the term; I mean: f(f(a,b), c) = f(a, b, c)).

In principle, this is not true for the median. However, as your neighbourhoods in (x,y) and z are both fairly large, I would assume that associativity still approximately holds (unless your data is drawn from a whacky distribution which it probably is not as this looks like some sort of imaging data). If I were you, I would test on some test data if applying the median in z first and then the median filter (or maybe even a mean filter) in (x,y) results in an unacceptable error compared to computing the median exactly by filtering in (x,y,z) simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. You're right about applying the mean. The first version of my algorithm was implemented using the mean and the result was not bad. But I noticed that the median improve the results because I have many values contaminated with noise. I will certainly have different results because there are many zeros that should be discarded (I edited the original post to include this important information), but maybe the median (x, y) on the median of an axis (z) has an intermediate behavior between the result of the full median (x, y, z) and the mean (x, y, mean (z)).